# Why did I lose the ability to print to a networked printer?

Tags: network, printing

I have a Canon iP3600 printer connected to a networked hard drive and up until a few days ago I was able to print from it. however, i have now lost the ability to print ever since i downloaded Apple's updated software for the printer!

I have my mac partitioned and running Windows 7 and can still print perfectly from there, so the cables are obviously not the problem. I can still print perfectly if I connect the printer via USB directly to the Mac. I can even print a test page from the Print preferences page.

I just cannot print from a document. Print Queue keeps saying "Copying print data" but nothing happens! Have downloaded the latest driver from the Canon website and deleted and re-installed the printer several times and several ways to no avail.

Any ideas most welcome...

Comment: Are you getting any error messages when you try to print?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and this is what I did to fix it:

1. Go to `http://localhost:631/`

   If you get the "Web Interface is Disabled" message, run `cupsctl WebInterface=yes` in Terminal.
2. Choose the **Administration** tab.

   [image]
3. Click Add Printer.

   [image]

   If you are required to login, use a local Administrator account.
4. Select the printer (in my case it was automatically found).

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem, installed driver numerous times, repaired permissions etc.. Then I installed Gutenprint ([main page](http://gimp-print.sourceforge.net/), [Mac OSX page)](http://gimp-print.sourceforge.net/MacOSX.php) and can print using that, although it seems to be terribly slow on my MP800R. Would still love to hear a different solution for getting the Canon drivers to work.

[edit]
After some more fiddling I got it working. Instead of adding the printer as an IP printer using LPD I added it via CUPS (http://localhost:631) and there for the connection I could choose canonijnetwork://Canon/MP800R?00.00.85.62.b9.2f The last bit will be different for everyone as it is the printer model and mac address. But after doing that I could print using the canon driver and also see the supply levels.

Comment: Have tried the above, but where is it you enter the canonijnetwork://Canon/iP3600?00.c0.02.F1.D2.16, which are my details. Although I'm not sure on how to check the model.